# How to install Pyjnius on ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, pyjnius

Who can guide me step by step I am a beginner and I trying to figure out how to install pyjnius.
Thank You Regards.

Comment: Maybe this will help, http://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: When i type sudo python setup.py install  python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Pyjnius depends on Cython and Java. Assuming that you already have Java installed. Please do the following:

```
su
pip install cython
pip install pyjnius
```

## Example - Installation

[image]

## A minimal Pyjnius example

[image]

Comment: i have try so much methods and SystemError: Error calling dlopen    Thanks

Comment: I used root user to execute the installation and I have no problem installing it. Can you please paste the complete error that you have encountered?

Comment: SystemError: Error calling dlopen(usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so: usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Thanks for the help, i install pyjnius but when in python i type import jnius appears this error,im a beginner but i think i have not set good the file .bashrc,but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have tried with the minimal Pyjnius example with problem as per my print screen.

Comment: Start Python interpreter and type "from jnius import autoclass". Do you get an error?