# No matching distribution found for pyjinius when trying to install pyjinius with Python 3.6

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-3.6, pyjnius

I am trying to run a kivy example App on Android, but it depends on the pyjinius library.  I cannot seem to install pyjinius on Ubuntu 18.

I tried installing pyjinius using

```
pip3 install pyjinius
```

which did not work.  It gave me the following error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyjinius (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyjinius

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46367417/how-to-install-pyjnius-on-ubuntu-16-04-64-bit), that I should try

```
pip install pyjinius
```

Pip was not installed so I firstly installed it with

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

I then used the above links' command

```
pip install pyjinius
```

but got the following error:

> ```
> Collecting pyjinius
> Exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>     status = self.run(options, args)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
>     wb.build(autobuilding=True)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
>     self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
>     ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
>     require_hashes
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
>     self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
>     all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
>     for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
>     page = self._get_page(location)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
>     return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
>     resp.raise_for_status()
>   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
>     raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
> HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/pyjinius/
> ```

I want to install pyjinius on Ubuntu 18 running python3.6 using pip3.   Alternatively, I want to install pyjinius with pip and overcome above exception.

#### Answer

Knowing how to install a package but not spelling it correctly was my error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Pyjnius on ubuntu 16.04 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46367417/how-to-install-pyjnius-on-ubuntu-16-04-64-bit)

Comment: The package is called **pyjnius**: `pip install Cython && pip install pyjnius`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyjinius (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyjinius

means that there is no such package `pyjinius` available for installation. There are many possibilities why this might happen.

However, I think you just have a simple typo in the package name. Do you mean https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius?

```
pip3 install pyjnius
```